"聞けたら聞いてる" what does it mean? Is it some grammar?
俺だって聞けたら聞いてるよ!
The character got told "Why don't you ask your friend about it?" and then in the next dialog he reflects on that and says this.
I think he's saying it like "If I could ask, I'd ask!" but why is てる used over the simple  聞く? is it a specific grammar point?

Another way to say the same thing: 聞けると思えば聞いた

^ 違うと思いますけど・・。「聞けるもんなら聞いてるよ」に近いんじゃないかと思いますが

It's difficult to be certain without context, but this almost certainly means If I could ask, I'd have asked (already)!
That is, ている is being used here in the resultative sense, meaning have already asked. So if you think of 聞けたら聞く as If I could ask I would, 聞けたら聞いている would be If I could ask/could have asked, I would have.
